# Probability of an even sum

Tags: probability, number-theory

In a set of numbers there are 5 even numbers and 4 odd numbers. If two numbers are chosen at random from the set, without replacement, what is the probability that the sum of these two numbers is even?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  to get an even sum, you need two odds or two evens.

Added:  to get two evens is $\frac 59 \cdot \frac 48$.  Can you get the chance of two odds?  As they are disjoint, you can add them.

Comment: would the answer be 1/3?

Comment: The answer is not 1/3. It might be more useful if you would say what you tried; then someone might suggest where you went wrong.

Comment: is the naswer 5/9?

Comment: I don't think this is an effective approach to the problem.

Comment: i took the probability of getting an odd number first then the probability of getting another odd from the remaining 8 numbers, then i did the same for even numbers.

Comment: and i got 1/3 please help!

Comment: What probabilities did you take, and what did you do when you put them together, and what was the result?

Comment: first i took 5/9 then multiplied this with 1/2

Comment: any help is appreaciated

Comment: @Daniel: Use Millikan hint, you will surely find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used the hint given by Ross Millikan answer.

P(the sum of the two numbers is even)=p(1st even and 2nd even)+p(1st odd and 2nd odd)

$$\implies p(even sum)=\frac{5}{9}\times\frac{4}{8}+\frac{4}{9}\times \frac{3}{8}=\frac{20}{72}+\frac{12}{72}=\frac{4}{9} $$

Therefore the probability that the sum of the two numbers is even is $\frac{4}{9}$.